# ArgumentError:Factory not registered: user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am writing the rspec for one of the method in user model:

```
describe "#generate_password_reset_token!" do
    subject { user }
    let!(:user) { create(:user) }

    it "changes the password_reset_token attribute" do
        expect { user.generate_password_reset_token! }.to change { user.password_reset_token }
    end
end
```

I ran the test and it said

```
Failure/Error: let!(:user) {create(:user)}
ArgumentError:
  Factory not registered: user
```

Here is the set up:

```
config.before(:all) do
   FactoryGirl.reload
end

config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
config.before(:suite) { DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation }
config.before(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.start }
config.after(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.clean }
```

I am using rails 4. What is the problem here?

Comment: Where is your `:user` factory?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Factory for your user:

**spec/factories/users.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'example@email.com'
  end
end
```

See 'Defining Factories' in http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md